# Which phrase does not match the others about ratios?

Tags: phrase-usage

Which ratio does not belong w/the other three?

> 2 parts to 5 parts
>
> 2 out of every 5
>
> 2 for each 5
>
> 2 for every 5

Comment: 2 parts to 5 parts includes 7 parts total. The others include a total of 5.

Answer (score 1):

**2 out of every 5** is different. There are 5 parts total. 2 parts of something and 3 parts of something else.

The other three have 7 parts total. 2 parts of something and 5 parts of something else.